# Is precum pure or unpure?

Tags: taharah

I am a boy.
Some precum came out of my private part and touched it and then rubbed my hand with a cloth to remove the wetness,then I go to the washroom to clean my hands.i touched the washroom door handle.

I wanted to know if precum is pure or not,and whether the cloth with which I rubbed my hands is pure or not,and whether the door handle is pure or not.(I touched the door handle with dry hands).
on other website it says that it is not impure.

Answer (score 0):

In our Hanafi Fiqh its unpure/najas/napak.